# Custom key combination doesn't work

Tags: shortcut-keys, 16.10

I'm trying to control the volume of a nearby music player by sending a command to the server. That is easy enough:

```
echo "[mac address] mixer volume -10" | nc server 9090
```

works perfectly from the command line and decreases the volume by 10 points. Likewise, +10 increases the volume. Now I want to assign these commands to key combinations <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>, respectively. I open up the System Settings/Keyboard panel and enter two custom key combinations. However, these don't work: nothing happens when I press the keys.

I tried adding full paths to `echo` (`/bin/echo`) and `nc` (`/bin/nc`); then I tried redirecting the SYSOUT and SYSERR of the `nc` command to some log file, but nothing shows up (but then, `nc` is not supposed to output anything). Finally, I put the string `[mac address] mixer volume -10` in a file called `.softer` and set the key combination to

`/bin/nc server 9090 < /home/jos/.softer`

Likewise with `.louder`. Still, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong? Again, all versions of these commands do work and change the volume if issued from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible answer (I usually use it) is to create `.sh` file containing this command then assign a `bash /path/to/sh-file` command using shortcuts this should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes, that works! Thanks. I will accept your answer unless someone comes up with a better idea. I think this restriction (that only bash scripts can be assigned to a key combination, not single commands) should be clear from the UI.

Comment: glad that I helped you, and I'll try to find a better (general case) answer